# Javascript Convert Integer property to String Property for all objects in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Fellow Javascript developers, how do I change a property's value from Int/Double to String for all the objects in an array?

```
Original Array

data = [
  Object {
    "id": 2138,
    "name": "Steve",
    "email": "steve.adams@gmail.com",
    "phone": 8745235698,
    "addressLine1": "Some Nice Address",
    "shopId": 115,
  },
  Object {
    "id": 2139,
    "name": "Chris",
    "email": "chris.austins@gmail.com",
    "phone": 9865345689,
    "addressLine1": "Vhjhjg",
    "shopId": 115,
  },
  Object {
    "id": 2140,
    "name": "Melinda",
    "email": "melinda@velvetjewels.com",
    "phone": 9867626833,
    "addressLine1": "California",
    "shopId": 115,
  }
]
```

I have a Multipicker Library which needs the `id` property to be a String Value when I pass the array to it. When the id is not a String, I don't see any data in the library to select.

I've tried to use the `map()` function, but I couldn't retain the object. What I got was only an array of string ids.

```
//Tried Map Method
let customers = data.map((item) => (item.id = String(item.id)));
console.log("fixed array", customers);

result ["2138","2139","2140"]
```

I also want to retain the original array, so if possible please provide a solution using the `map()` function, since it returns a new array without mutating the original one. Or any other method which doesn't mutate the original array

```
//Expected Result
//id's changed to String

customers = [
  Object {
    "id": "2138",
    "name": "Steve",
    "email": "steve.adams@gmail.com",
    "phone": 8745235698,
    "addressLine1": "Some Nice Address",
    "shopId": 115,
  },
  Object {
    "id": "2139",
    "name": "Chris",
    "email": "chris.austins@gmail.com",
    "phone": 9865345689,
    "addressLine1": "Vhjhjg",
    "shopId": 115,
  },
  Object {
    "id": "2140",
    "name": "Melinda",
    "email": "melinda@velvetjewels.com",
    "phone": 9867626833,
    "addressLine1": "California",
    "shopId": 115,
  }
]
```

Comment: Just loop over the original array and set `thing.id = thing.id.toString()`.  You don't need to map if you are wanting to mutate the original.  Just loop it.

Comment: `data.forEach(it => it.id = it.id.toString())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a map, you must return the modified object :

```
let customers = data.map( item => {
     item.id = String(item.id);
     return item;
});
```

But you don't need a map. You can just iterate this way :

```
data.forEach(item => item.id = String(item.id)) // or "" + item.id, or item.id.toString()
```